# How to create a well-formatted word document(.DOC) in python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, ms-word

I want to create new work document from sketch with Python on Linux platform, but do not know how to do that.

I do not willing to use RTF or use pythondocx to create docx document. Is there any other way to do so? Remember, I need the document keeps the formatting.

Thanks everyone's help!

Comment: Go ahead and get started on this.  When you have a specific programming problem or question, come back and ask us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python docx module](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) allows you to do what you want. It is perfect for you and is as simple as working with any other Python library.

Answer (score 1):

Openoffice has some Python scripting ability. I only heard about it, haven't studied it nor used it.